# Is there any event for new @Input to a component?

Tags: angular

In case you want to know why I need this:

I have a component for showing phone contacts. It gets the account it should present his contacts.

For implementing search inside that component I should (currect me if I'm wrong) make a second array that has all the contacts and filter him.
For that I need to know when a new account is coming to the component and change the new array for the search every time it heppends.

If there is a smarter way to implement search and filter, I would like to hear. But anyways I would like to know how to know when a new input comes in.

**I would like to have something like this:**

```
export class ContactTable
{
  @Input(newAccountCame) account:Account;
  private newAccountCame()
  {
     //do something with this.account.
  }
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`ngOnChanges`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/OnChanges-class.html) callback

```
  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    console.log('ngOnChanges - account = ' + changes['account'].currentValue);
  }
```

or you can make `account` a setter

```
  private _account:Account;
  @Input() 
  private set newAccountCame(value)
  {
     this._account = value;
     //do something with this.account.
  }
```

You should be aware that none of these will work if only values are added/removed from an array that was previously passed in. Only when a different array is passed will change detection recognize it and call the method or the setter.

If you need to handle this case use [`ngDoCheck`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/DoCheck-class.html)

Comment: Thanks for the quick help and the tips!